# get the id of super-parent <li> onclick on child anchor <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How can I get the id of an `<li>` on click on its child anchor `<a>` in a structure like shown below? :

```
<li id="idx"><h5><a class="trigger" href="#"></a></h5></li>
```

How can I return "`idx"` using jquery?

Comment: Could you show the JS code where you bind the handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.trigger').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ID = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on("click", "a.trigger", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var anchor = $(this);
    var id = anchor.closest("li").attr("id");
    console.log(id);
});
```

Running example: http://jsfiddle.net/nRaa4/